# Vue.js 'if - else' not working with font awesome

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is my code:

```
<tr v-for="(i,  index) in items.data">
  <td>{{ index }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.producer }}</td>
  <td><font-awesome-icon v-if="i.recieved" icon="check" /><font-awesome-icon v-else icon="times" /></td>
</tr>
```

I received data from server, where `i.recieved` can be `true` or `false`, but when I compile this, I always see only icon `times`. It is very strange because I have 4 received fields with true on my server.

So what do you think I should do?

In console I see only one error:

```
error: Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives (vue/require-v-for-key) at src/views/Home.vue:15:7:

> 15 |       <tr v-for="(i,  index) in items.data">
     |       ^
```

Comment: Install vue-dev-tools and make sure that you have items with i.received=true.

Comment: I can see it on server, so yes, I have

Comment: That was my fail! I wrote recieved, non received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning says, you need to add a key. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Try this.

```
<tr v-for="(i,  index) in items.data" :key="index">
  <td>{{ index }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.producer }}</td>
  <td><font-awesome-icon v-if="i.recieved" icon="check" /><font-awesome-icon v-else icon="times" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That was my fail! I wrote recieved, non received

Answer (score 0):

Your console errors comes because your v-for has no key defined.

It is recommended to provide a key with v-for whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.

Since it’s a generic mechanism for Vue to identify nodes, the key also has other uses that are not specifically tied to v-for, as we will see later in the guide.

[More Info about the Key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)